# Broken colorbox link in a drupal site

Tags: css, drupal, colorbox

Anyone have any idea why the colorbox for the video link at the top of:

http://www.headlineitstore.com/about/headline-it

doesn't work, yet it works with the same exact link on the front page of:

http://www.headlineitstore.com/

Same exact link, copied over, yet it does

Thanks!

Comment: H.html(J.close).show is not a function - that's what happens on the first link when I click the video. You'll need to turn off Boost's JS compression to really dig into that, since all the site scripts are in one file at the moment.

Comment: Hmm. Odd. Any clue why it would be doing that on only that page, but not the front page? I'll def have to look into that. Did you see that via firebug?

Comment: Yes indeed, firebug. My first thought would be that some module or theme is manipulating the script includes in preprocess_page, but  really I don't have any great ideas.

Comment: By the way, not to be captain obvious, but make sure you have the newest/correct versions of everything. After that, find the line in the colorbox module that adds the script that's not always getting inserted, and work backward from there to see why it's only called on some pages but not others. Sorry to not be more specific, I've never had that happen.

Comment: Yeah, it's quite odd. I'll take a better look at it today, was kind of a late post for me yesterday. It's odd that it works everywhere else except that page.

Comment: hrm, the JS is the exact same on both pages

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be adding a class of cboxElement to anything, that is something that the colorbox plugin adds itself for some internal tracking purposes.  Instead of adding that class, follow your plugin's directions for assigning colorbox to your page elements.

When I assign the plugin using a jQuery selector (the way it is intended to be used), your video link works fine.  Example:

```
$(".frontPageVid").colorbox({width:500, height:500, iframe:true})
```